# AWS Bandwidth data transfer out beyond the global free tier dramatically increased

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, data-transfer, billing

I'm new to AWS. I launched a EC2 instance and some S3 buckets in April.

The cost of AWS in April and May are normal, but the cost of AWS in June are **doubly increased**.

I went to the Bills Page to check and I found that the **data transfer** is abnormal.

Here are the pictures about the cost in May and June:

[image: (May)]

[image: (June)]

I didn't change anything except the ssh setting of EC2's (myip -> anywhere).

Can anyone tell me where should I check my setting first?

Comment: Have you read the logs for your S3 buckets?

Comment: No, I haven't.Should I open the logging first?

Comment: Yes.  You'll need to [enable logging on your buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to:

- **Data Transfer in May:** 48 GB for $4.36
- **Data Transfer in June:** 319 GB for $28.71

Data Transfer is charged for **outbound** traffic to the Internet. The [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides an initial 15GB at no charge. Thereafter, the charge depends upon your Region. It appears that you are in the USA, where the rate is $0.09/GB.

There has been **no price increase on AWS**. In fact, AWS [just announced their 62nd price reduction](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-price-reduction-sql-server-standard-edition-on-ec2/). Rather, the cause of the increased charge is the fact that your account **consumed more data transfer** in June (319 GB) than in May (45 GB).

Data transfer would include users on the Internet accessing your web servers, any downloads from AWS (eg from Amazon S3) and everything else causing data to go from AWS to the Internet.

If you think this is too high, you should examine the services you are running and, in particular, make sure you are not serving large content from Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think it is too high,where should I check my services first? I just opened the logging in S3 buckets.

Comment: Hi, I set up a VM on AWS and did some basic ssh and git operations (pulling and pushing some code) without using it as a server or uploading large files, and within one day I used 1GB. May I ask what might have caused such a large usage of data transfer?

Comment: @instant501 Data Transfer is charged for **outbound** traffic to the Internet. That would suggest that 1GB of data went from your EC2 instance (or other AWS services) to the Internet, at a cost of about 9c.